# AH10411 Error following Apache update - redirects with space (%20)

Tags: apache, redirect

Following an Apache update, my redirects which have worked for years now do not work if the URLs include a space or encoded space %20.

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*)$ /Forum/blog.php?mode=view&un=$1 [L]
```

This line used to work but now results in a AH10411 error if there is a space - or %20 - in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the error you get has to do with the update on apache2 but you can try the quick fix below

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*)$ /Forum/blog.php?mode=view&un=$1 [B,NC,NE,L]
```

you can also ref link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

regards